# How to prevent the mat-form-filed focusing while Clicking on the mat-select on mat-options or mat-chip-list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a form using angular (mat-form-filed) in my application, inside the mat-form-filed I have an input tag, mat-option, mat-select, and mat-chip-list, I am facing an issue that while clicking on the mat-select or on mat-chip-list  the input part gets focused can anyone help me to prevent the focusing issue and give me a solution

- ```
    <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'always'" appearance="none" class="cs-mat-labelset">
                                  <input id="FLD_institute_d_w_searchlist_institute_DUMMY$$name_input" matInput
                                      class="cs-lspad" type="text"
                                      [(ngModel)]="sectionObjectInfo['filterSectionDetail']['filterFields']['pfm138993_name_23']['fieldValue']">
                                  <mat-select matPrefix class="cs-matselectfield"
                                      [ngClass]="{'cs-matselect-operator':sectionObjectInfo['filterSectionDetail']['filterFields']['pfm138993_name_23']['conditionalOperator']}"
                                      [(value)]="sectionObjectInfo['filterSectionDetail']['filterFields']['pfm138993_name_23']['conditionalOperator']"
                                      (click)="cspfmListFilter.operatorStyle()">
                                      <mat-option
                                          id="{{'FLD_institute_d_w_searchlist_institute_DUMMY$$name_operator' + item['symbol']}}"
                                          *ngFor="let item of filterFieldTypeAndOperator[sectionObjectInfo['filterSectionDetail']['filterFields']['pfm138993_name_23']['fieldType']]"
                                          [value]="item['symbol']" [title]="item['displayName']">
                                          {{item['symbol']}}
                                      </mat-option>
                                  </mat-select>
                                  <mat-chip-list class="cs-mat-error">
                                      <mat-error>
                                          <span *ngIf="!sectionObjectInfo['filterSectionDetail']['filterFields']['pfm138993_name_23']['isValidField']">
                                                  {{this.sectionObjectInfo['filterSectionDetail']['filterFields']['pfm138993_name_23']['errorMessage']}}</span> 
                                      </mat-error>
                                  </mat-chip-list>
                              </mat-form-field>
  ```

  **I have attached the HTML above**

Actual result is [I have clicked on the mat-select but my input box getting foccuesd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuRCp.png)

I am expecting the result like only while clicking on the input box it must be focused and while clicking on mat-select or any other place inside the mat-form-field the the input box must not get focused